# Only certain users can no longer receive notifications on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

Only certain users can no longer receive notifications from my app. I was able to re-produce this with a test account but I dont know how and removing/adding the application doesn't seem to fix the problem.

This application is only being used by 4-5 testers and the number of notifications being sent to any given user is very nominal and nobody has reported them as spam.

I am using rails 2.2.2 and Facebooker.

The way I am sending notifications is via creating a new session and calling send_notification from that session.

```
ses = Facebooker::Session.create
ses.send_notification(fbuid, "hay there")
```

I don't get any errors, just simple that the user doesn't receive the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limits to how many notifications can be sent to users each day.

There is both a limit for user to user notifications and application to user notifications.

You can determine each of these limits by calling:

```
Facebooker::Session.create.post('facebook.admin.getAllocation', :integration_point_name => 'announcement_notifications_per_week')
Facebooker::Session.create.post('facebook.admin.getAllocation', :integration_point_name => 'notifications_per_day')
```

It appears developers of the application can receive an unlimited amount, so you may want to make your test accounts developers.

Also, the first parameter to send_notification needs to be an array. Your usage of the variable name "fbuid" suggests you might be passing a single integer.

Good luck!

Comment: If you look at the value of :integration_point_name I think you'll see your answer ;-)

(And just in case you don't, user to user is per day and application to user is per week)